# Is there a way i can run my GTK program (C) on a PIC circuit?

Tags: c, ubuntu, gtk, pic

I never before had worked with PIC circuits, i recently was asked to run my C program, with GTK libraries on a PIC circuit, is that posible?
As far as i know pic cant run GUI or Ubuntu .

Im sorry if the question is kinda dumb, but im all ears to advice

Comment: Given the memory constraints of a PIC microcontroller, and the shear amount of work involved in trying (and failing) to port the GTK+ libraries, probably not.

Answer (score 2):

PIC series are 8-32 Bit micro controllers. There is no way for them to support an OS such as Linux/Unix/Windows with OpenGL support. So, that means, even though you manage to handle the SDRAM and HDD/SSD problems by using external ram and eeproms, you will have to write a huge amount of code, such that GTK+ will be a superficial API for you. At that point, it does not matter if the API is called GTK+ or not.

Seriously though, don't do it.

Comment: I know, its not efficient at all, hell i dont think its even posible, rigth now im just a trainee but they dont listen to me, they want a pic to support GUI interface, a nice looking one, with button, css animations, etc.

Comment: PICs are microcontrollers that are cheap for a reason: they are for (very) lightweight work. If they want cheap stuff and a GTK+ gui, run a raspberry pi.

Comment: There is however something called the [Aria User Interface Library](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/MPLAB%20Harmony%20Graphics%20Libraries%20Help.pdf) for PICs. That's not GTK+, but maybe that's decent enough. Here are some [demos](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/help_apps_gfx.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

So, it seems there are GUIs on modern PIC chips:

http://www.microchip.com/design-centers/graphics

However, you won't run a Linux nor GTK+ on it, you will need to use the dedicated graphic libraries provided by microchip.